# Granting bounty to question asked by another account owned by same person

Tags: discussion, bounty

Suppose a person has 2 accounts. He asked a question using account X. Then, he grants bounty on the question using account Y which has far more points. Is this against the rules?

Comment: As long as he isn't using one of his accounts as an upvote machine, I see no problem with it. It's ... curious, but I don't think it's against the rules.

Answer (score 3):

In general: you cannot use multiple accounts to do things you wouldn't be able to do with only one. For example: you wouldn't be able to grant a bounty to yourself with one account, thus using a second to award the bounty to yourself is not allowed.

Another good rule of thumb is that both of your accounts should never appear on the same page together. If they do, you're probably doing something wrong.